# FindFirstFile() return ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND for existing folder after several loop

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, filesystems

I have code that pretty simple, checking the directory presence or not. we run this code multiple times before specific action for initialization purpose.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(mConfig.mOutputDir->c_str(), &ffd);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
{   
    wprintf(L"Warning: Output Directory may not exist\n");
    wprintf(L"Error : %d\n",GetLastError());
} 

if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
{
    wprintf(L"Warning: Output Directory is not valid directory\n");
}
```

The value of `mConfig.mOutputDir->c_str()` is valid directory and never changed during runtime. The problem is after around 1000 call to the code above, the `FindFirstFile()` start to return error with code `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.

I have tried other API, which is `GetAttributes()`, and it fails at the same sequence with error code `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`

Additionally, when I run the program on VeraCrypt Volume, the failure appears earlier in the loop compared to running the program on normal volume.

I also tried to call `FindClose()` API after the `FindFirstFile()` but no difference

I'm running the program in windows 10 64 bit, the code itself is compiled using Visual Studio 2005.

Is there any bug for Windows File System API?

Comment: The most reasonable explanation is that `mConfig.mOutputDir` is not what you believe it is. What does your debugger show you?

Comment: On a side note, you should do `GetLastError()` before you do anything else when there's an error. Other functions might modify it, and then you've lost your error.

Comment: @molbdnilo the value of `mConfig.mOutputDir` is consistent and not changed prior to the error. I've tried to hardcoded the value as well and the problem is still there. regarding the `GetLastError()`, I've tried to read it first time and the error code is consistent.